# What can I get out of the following autocorrelation function of a time series?

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I have the following blot that represents a time series of sensor's readings (1 reading per hour) and then I have the plot of the PACF and ACF functions. How can I make use of these plots according to Box-Jenkins methodology to select an ARIMA i.e. How can I know the grades of the ARIMA model I should use regarding these plots[image: Time series plot over 24 readings]

[image: ACF, PACF]